# iphone MPMoviePlayerViewController : extract total duration

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

how can i get the video'a total time, before it plays the video in MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get total duration of movie you can use :

1). Use `AVPlayerItem` class and `AVFoundation` and `CoreMedia framework`. (I have used `UIImagePickerController` for picking the movie)

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAsset.h>

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    selectedVideoUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:selectedVideoUrl];

    CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
    float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
    NSLog(@"duration: %.2f", seconds);
}
```

2). **MPMoviePlayerController** has a property `duration` .Refer [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/duration)

Comment: In MPMoviePlayerController, before we actually play video, duration is zero. If you get by any way, plz add code

Comment: it represents the duration of what have currently been buffered, not the total duration.

Comment: First option did worked successfully, Thanks a lot. You made the day.. :)

Answer (score 3):

**To get the total Duration in MPMoviePlayerViewController**

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp;
float seconds =mp.moviePlayer.duration;
```

**Note: Above code give the total Duration of related Media in seconds**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to get the total time from MPMoviePlayerViewController's [`duration`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/duration) property (because that brings up the movie player UI), you could instead create an `AVAsset` object with your video file passed in via a file URL and then check the [`duration`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAsset/duration) property on that.

This trick would only work on iOS 5 (which is where AVAsset's [`assetWithURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVAsset/assetWithURL%3a) came in with).

Answer (score 0):

YOu can get using this method in swift

```
func getMediaDuration(url: NSURL!) -> Float64{
        var asset : AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset.assetWithURL(url) as AVURLAsset
        var duration : CMTime = asset.duration

        return CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
    }
```